# Get Data From Button Click on AutoGenerated Button - jQuery Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I need to be able to get the context of the button that was clicked on a jQuery dialog.

I have a function that auto creates a dialog with a button name array I pass it. The function looks like this.

```
function setAutoDialog(buttonNameArray){
    var testArray = buttonNameArray;
    var passDataBack = function () {
        var test = $('.getButtonClicked').text(); // NEED THE TEXT FROM THE BUTTON THAT WAS CLICKED HERE
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
    var myButtons = {};

    for(var i=0; i<testArray.length; i++){
        myButtons[testArray[i]] = passDataBack;
    }

    $('#autoDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        dialogClass: 'autoDialog',
        width: 'auto',
        buttons : myButtons
    });
}
```

I am not sure what selector I need to use to get the value of the button that was clicked on the dialog.  For example, if you have a button named "Cancel", when I click "Cancel" I need to get that text and perform operations on said text.  (Pass it back to main screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

On your handler, pass the click event into the function. Like so.

```
$('#button1').live('click', function () {    
    setAutoDialog(buttonArray, $(this));
    $( "#autoDialog" ).dialog("open");
});
```

Then in your function reference the event and get the textContent from the target.

```
function setAutoDialog(buttonNameArray, clickEvent){
    var testArray = buttonNameArray;
    var passDataBack = function (clickEvent) {
        var t2 = clickEvent.target.textContent;

        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
    var myButtons = {};

    for(var i=0; i<testArray.length; i++){
        myButtons[testArray[i]] = passDataBack;
    }

    $('#autoDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        dialogClass: 'autoDialog',
        width: 'auto',
        buttons : myButtons
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case i use callback function

buttons : [
            {
              label: "Close",
              callback: function() {
                App.ModalDialog.close();
              } // callback
            }
          ]